flink restart strategy issue
When I submit a job to a Flink 1.19.1 Standalone Cluster and configure the Fixed Delay Restart Strategy, I intentionally use numeric/0 in the job to trigger an exception. However, during the next restart attempt, the job state unexpectedly shows as Finished.
enter image description here
The third-party dependency packages are as followsenter image description here

What is the value for restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
